# PHP AJAX Getting undefined index id ,tried many ways couldnt solve it

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm making an click event in which I send the `id` of the employee. I can see the value using `console.log()`; the employee id is getting shown, but I keep getting an index :id error.

```html
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Appointment Letter" onclick="downloadempappointmentletter('<?php echo $data->employee_id;?>')">
```

```js
function downloadempappointmentletter(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Admin/Employee/downloadappointmentletter",
    data: { id: id },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
```

```php
public function downloadappointmentletter()
{
  $empid = $_POST['id'];
}
```

I keep getting error:

> undefined index :id

However when I `echo $data->employee_id;` it shows 1 etc. What am I missing?

Comment: `but I keep getting an index :id error`. When? Where? What's the exact response from console.log? Are you trying to access the page manually in your browser to test or something?

Comment: Im tryin to make a pdf for an individual employee based on his id ,so when an employee click on download ,i send his id through ajax and make corresponding pdf letter ,if i send staticaly employee id everything works fine but i need to change it to dynamically thats when i get this error undefined index :id

Comment: in console.log(data); is it shows employee id or not?

Comment: it shows in console.log(data)

Answer (score 0):

*You just comment $empid = $_POST['id']; this line and var_dump($_POST); it will shows all $_POST values from  ajax*

look through  browser Network tab ,check ajax post id or not after that we can follow up the problem

Comment: i get array(0) { } when var_dump($_POST)

Comment: var_dump($_POST)  returns empty , it means ajax doesn't post nothing to  php function , Please check browser console & network  -> header tabs ,it will show errors and post data key and value

Comment: array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } This is what response i get in network tab

Comment: Are you actually saying that when you go directly to `Admin/Employee/downloadappointmentletter` in your browser, you are seeing the error? Because that would be expected as that would be a GET request, not POST. You JS from what you're saying works correctly as expected.

Comment: im using only post method @JonStirling but why it keeps showing the error? In network tab i check it i get this error

Comment: You just said `array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } This is what response i get in network tab `, but now you're saying it gives you an error? Which is it!?

Comment: yes thats whats confusing when i try to print $empid it gives this response but when i remove print_r and exit ,it gives undefined index @JonStirling

Comment: This result means your request return php var_dump  value now it's working 

Please give Network url screen shot

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" class="mybutton btn btn-primary" value="Appointment Letter"
  data-value="<?php echo $data->employee_id; ?>">
```

now

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".mybutton ").click(function(){
      let id = $(this).attr('data-value');
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Admin/Employee/downloadappointmentletter",
          data: { id: id },
          success: function (data) {
                  console.log(data);
          }
      });
   }); 
 });
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token getting this error :

Comment: let id = $(this).attr('data-value); this is the line showing error

Comment: there is no change in your comment ??

Comment: still getting the same error ,when i passed staticaly it works

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Appointment Letter" onclick="downloadempappointmentletter('<= $data->employee_id ?>')">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function downloadempappointmentletter(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Admin/Employee/downloadappointmentletter",
    data: { "id": id },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
```

Try this. I think you forgot ("") when sending data

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it instead of an onclick event ,i made it work through calling it in `<a href="">`

Answer (score -1):

```
function downloadempappointmentletter(id) {
  var ID = id;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Admin/Employee/downloadappointmentletter",
    data: { id: ID },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
```